# How do I compare a character to all the characters in some string in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, character, string-comparison

I need to write a function that takes a character and a string as inputs and then compares that character to each element in the string. It then prints and finally returns the number of times that the character appeared in the string.

This is the code I've come up with, but it isn't working out the right way. I'd appreciate it if someone could explain and correct the error.

I thought first to write a function that compares two characters to check if they are equal, like this:

```
def func1(x1, x2):
    if x1 == x2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

And then, I thought I'd wite the other, main function like this:

```
def func2():
    ch1 = input("Enter one character. ")
    str1 = str(input("Enter a string. "))
    list_1 = list(str1)
    a = 0
    for 1 in list_1:
        if func1(ch1, list_1):
            a += 1
        else:
            a += 0
        print(a)
        return a
```

What is the error here? If I choose "a" as my character, and then enter a string of five a's as my string, the function still tells me that "a" appeared in the string only once. Why is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: This may help you to solve the problem without your extra function - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877671/counting-vowels-in-a-string-using-recursion

The accepted answer has recursive and iterative ways to count the vowels in a given string. If you change the comparison to just check against one char rather than an string of vowels, you should be on the right track :)

Comment: I really don't understand for why you wrote this function:
`def func1(x1, x2)`. Even if you want separate function for that you can write
`def func1(x1, x2):
    return x1 == x2`

Comment: @DenisNikanorov that's fine, that is how every person who starts programming writes code, he will improve will time. But good to make that comment though

Answer (score 7):

`"YourString".count("Char")` will do

Answer (score 3):

Few possible ways.

Using list

```
>>> len([x for x in test_string if x == test_char])
```

Using collections.Counter

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> print(Counter(test_string)[test_char])
```

Comment: +1 for using list comprehension, a very nice feature of python.

Comment: @Saher, but not really appropriate here as it creates a temporary list when you really just need to keep count of one thing.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your immediate problem, you just need to dedent the print and return

```
def func2():
    ch1 = input("Enter one character. ")
    str1 = str(input("Enter a string. "))
    list_1 = list(str1)
    a = 0
    for 1 in list_1:
        if func1(ch1, list_1):
            a += 1
        else:
            a += 0
    print(a)  # <-- dedent
    return a  # <-- dedent
```

You don't need to convert the string to a list to iterate over it. You don't need the `else` clause if it doesn't do anything. You shouldn't return from inside the for loop

```
def func2():
    ch1 = input("Enter one character. ")
    str1 = input("Enter a string. ")
    a = 0
    for c in str1:
        if c == ch:
            a += 1
        print(a)
    return a
```

More simply

```
def func2():
    ch1 = input("Enter one character. ")
    str1 = input("Enter a string. ")
    return str1.count(ch1)
```

Comment: That works, but I have to use the first function I have up there within the second function. I would do it the way you suggest, and I agree it's easier, but I was was told to do it a very specific way for a homework assignment. Thanks.

Comment: @IvanLesiv, you can simplify func1. `def func1(x1, x2): return x1 == x2`

Comment: I did that. I simplified func1 and moved the return statement into the proper block, but I have to construct func2 in such a way that it includes func1. I tried to do that and the fuction only prints out a bunch of zeros, (one zero for every character in the string).

Comment: Nope, forget it. Your more simplified example works just fine. But when I try the longer piece of code with the for loop, I get a series of zeros printed out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple code that does what you want:

It returns the number of times the character ch appears in text.

```
def test(ch, text): // ch is character and text is the string
    numAppears = 0
    for t in text:
        if t == ch:
            numAppears += 1
    return numAppears
```

example:

```
>>> test("a", "saherbaderahwal")
4
>>> test("c", "hello")
0
>>> test(" ", "nice to meet you")
3
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `return` is indented one block to deep, so after comparing the first character of the list, the function returns.

(Another problem is that your function `func1` is not only poorly named, but also far too complicated:

```
def cmp_chars(x, y):
    return x == y
```

Though you really don't need a function for that at all.)

Comment: That's part of the isse, but not the whole thing. I did what you suggested, but now, when I take, say, "a" as my character, and "aaaaa" as my string, instead of printing out 5, the fuctio prints out 0 five times.

Answer (score 0):

assuming the code you put there is correctly formatted unindent your `return` one block - it looks like it's getting called once throught the for block